# DAX - RT Measure calculation based on specific selected date in slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have a problem regarding my calculation. I want to visualize the running total over time (for example 01.07 after hours rounded to the nearest half hour to reduce computing power). I have 90 days of data in my dataset. The Problem i have is that the calculation for the dates long time ago (for example 01.12.2021) are super fast and the calculation for recent dates (05.07.2022) are super slow. I think that the measure calculates the running total for the whole column and then the date filter will be applied, which caused the extreme long calculation time for recent dates. Every day has the same amount of rows. Any idea how i can tell the measure to calculate the running total only for the selected date/date which i picked in my filter?

I used the following measures:

````
Average Sales =
'Measure Table X'[RT Sales] / 'Measure Table X'[RT Rows]
 
RT Sales = CALCULATE(
Sum('X'[Sales]),
'X'[Time rounded] <= Max('X'[Time rounded]))
 
RT Rows = CALCULATE(
COUNTA('X'[Time rounded]),
'X'[Time rounded] <= Max('X'[Time rounded]))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are going to achive, but you can try this, this can work faster.

```
Average Sales =
    CALCULATE(
        DIVIDE('Measure Table X'[RT Sales] , 'Measure Table X'[RT Rows])
        'X'[Time rounded] <= Max('X'[Time rounded]
    )
 
RT Sales = Sum('X'[Sales])
 
RT Rows =COUNTA('X'[Time rounded])
```

Comment: I have a Dashboard where i visualize sales count for every day in the last 90 days. You can filter to a specific date and see the sales after time for that day. The Problem ist that the calculation takes very long for recent dates and is extreme fast for dates long time ago. I tried your solution and it works perfect! Measure is very fast for all dates. Thank you very much mate ;)

Comment: You're Wellcome  )